# Angular JS table data scroll load more data from api/json

Tags: angularjs

i was use this demo [http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SRpL7/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBFRO.png) but i got error like [image]

please help me i need it.

Comment: explain more about your question

Comment: Did you copied code from jsfiddle into your application and got this error?

Comment: i have copied it but make  needfull changes. i little bit confuse about the api call could you please have any another example or demo